# Usage of MutationObserver in a page that is not dynamically modified

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

This seems like an obvious question but I can't find any definitive answer in any documentation.

I want to make sure that a function is ran when the page is loaded at first **and** when the page is modified by adding or removing a node.

Is a MutationObserver supposed to trigger on page load, at least once, when the DOM is parsed, even if there is no JS that adds or removes nodes?

My testing seems to indicate that it is. The Observer always gets at least one record, that includes the whole body of the document, when I get it to observe *document.body* with childList on true. However, I'd like to have a definitive answer, ideally from documentation (which I can't find), since perhaps this is browser dependant in some way.

This is the simple code I'm using to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>  
  <title>Observer test</title>
</head>
<body>              
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };

  function mutationCallback (mutationsList, observer) {
    console.log('Triggered');
      for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
       console.log(mutation.type);
       console.log(mutation.target);
         for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
           console.log(node)
         }
      }
  }
  observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
  observer.observe(document.body, config);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a MutationObserver supposed to trigger on page load, at least once, when the DOM is parsed, even if there is no JS that adds or removes nodes?

No, page load event is not related.

The observer is triggered only by DOM mutations (either in JS or in HTML parser) and you happen to have one here as well. To see it easily add a console.log for the entire list: `console.log(mutationsList)`

You will see that the only mutation is the addition of a text node containing spaces/newlines between the tags `</script>` and `</body>`.

[image]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So I'll have to use a regular old page load event to run my hook at least once, and let the observer handle the rest after that.
Thanks!

Comment: So the only case it wouldn't fire is if the script that did add the observer synchronously was the last node to be parsed, i.e `</script></body></html>`.

Comment: Got it, yes that's the case here. I just confirmed that if I remove the new lines between the closing tags then it doesn't fire at all.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you invoke the observe() function when you observe document.body.

If you invoke it in the head, it will observe the whole loading process of the body.

If you invoke it at the end of the body, it will not observe the part of the body already loaded.